# declare parameter subtype in Java interface, use subtypes in Java implementing methods

Tags: java, generics, interface, methods, extends

I want to declare a method in an interface where the parameter of the method defined in implementing classes can be a subtype of a specific java class for example:

```
interface Processor{
      processRequest( Request r);
}

public class SpecialRequest extends Request{...}

public class SpecialProcessor implements Processor{

      processRequest(SpecialRequest r){...}
}
```

but I get errors in the SpecialProcessor because it doesn't properly implement the Processor interface. What can I change in the Processor interface to allow the definition in the SpecialProcessor to work?

Answer (score 10):

You can type `Processor`:

```
public interface Processor<R extends Request> {
    void processRequest(R r);
}


public class SpecialProcessor implements Processor<SpecialRequest> {
    public void processRequest(SpecialRequest r) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's right - remember that a caller shouldn't know what specific implementation of the interface is being used.  They just know that they can pass a `Request` (**any** Request) to `processRequest`, whereas your implementation is imposing a stricter constraint on the argument that would cause certain method calls not to be type-correct.

If you want to do this, you'll need to add a generic parameter to the interface, something like the following:

```
interface Processor<R extends Request> {
    void processRequest(R r);
}

public class SpecialProcessor implements Processor<SpecialRequest> {

    public void processRequest(SpecialRequest r) { ... }

}
```

This way, callers that want to pass in "normal" requests will have to declare a variable/field of type `Processor<Request>` - and your SpecialProcessor no longer matches this bound, so cannot be assigned, and will correctly be rejected at compile-time.  Callers that are dealing with special requests themselves can use a `Processor<SpecialRequest>` variable/field, which your class *can* be assigned to.