# Declaring interface method to allow only implemented class

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface, restriction

I have interface Syncable:

```
public interface Syncable{
    public void sync(Syncable other);
}
```

And two implemented classes:

```
public class TstA implements Syncable{
    @Override
    public void sync(Syncable other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}

public class TstB implements Syncable{
    @Override
    public void sync(Syncable other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

So this code is legal:

```
TstA a = new TstA();
TstB b = new TstB();
a.sync(b);
```

This is not what I want. I want to allow a.sync receive instances of TstA, and b.sync receive instances of TstB.

Probably I have to use generics, but how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [declare paramter subtype in Java interface, use subtypes in Java implementing methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820159/declare-paramter-subtype-in-java-interface-use-subtypes-in-java-implementing-me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your interface generic:

```
public interface Syncable<T extends Syncable<T>> {
    public void sync(T other);
}
```

And implement a parameterized instance of that interface:

```
public class TstA implements Syncable<TstA> {
    @Override
    public void sync(TstA other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

Comment: This is strict enough for me, but not an end solution, as defining signature: interface Syncable<T extends Syncable<T>> doesn't infer that it will be used properly, and may be used like this: class TstA implements Syncable<TstB>

Comment: @AndreyP That is possible. But I guess you can't get around with that. :(

Comment: Is it possible to add restriction that: class T1 implements Syncable<T2> so that T1=T2  ?

Comment: @AndreyP No you can't do that. That kind of restriction is not possible.

Comment: @AndreyP: If the above way works for you, `interface Syncable<T>` would also work.

Comment: @newacct And that would allow the instantiation like this - `Syncable<Object>`, which is not valid as per requirement.

Comment: @RohitJain: Where does it say that `Syncable<Object>` is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Analogous to `Comparable`, this is how you would do it:

```
public interface Syncable<T> {
    public void sync(T other);
}

public class TstA implements Syncable<TstA> {
    @Override
    public void sync(TstA other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}

public class TstB implements Syncable<TstB> {
    @Override
    public void sync(TstB other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

If there were a generic class or method that required a type parameter `T` to be syncable to itself, then that class or method would declare the bound `T extends Syncable<? super T>`.